# Merge associative arrays by partial key match

Tags: php, arrays, merge, mapping, partial-matches

I have an array:

```
$a = [
    "g41" => 1,
    "g44" => 2,
    "g53" => 3
];
```

And another array is:

```
$list = [
    40,
    41,
    44,
    46,
    53
];
```

How to combine these arrays by partial key matches to produce the following results?

```
$result = [
    "41" => 1,
    "44" => 2,
    "53" => 3,
    "40" => null,
    "46" => null
];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you attempted to reach a solution on your own? While we are glad to help with any problems you run into, you are expected to make an effort of your own. If you have written some code, but got stuck, please edit the question and share it with us. Also, are keys in the first array always prefixed with `g`?

Comment: hi,yes first array always prefixed with g;

Answer (score 1):

Iterate `$list` array and check for the key in the other `$a` array:

```
$a = array("g41" => 1, "g44" => 2, "g53" => 3);
$list = array(40, 41, 44, 46, 53);

$result = [];
foreach ($list as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $a["g$key"] ?? null;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [40]=> NULL
  [41]=> int(1)
  [44]=> int(2)
  [46]=> NULL
  [53]=> int(3)
}
```

Comment: The result in this answer is not sorted as required.

Answer (score 0):

since you want to the result sequence follow `$a`, you may need to unset `$list`, and push remaining lists to `$result`

sample code as below:

```
<?php

$a=["g41"=>1,"g44"=>2,"g53"=>3];

$list=[40,41,44,46,53];

$result =[];

foreach($a as $key => $value){
  $new_key = substr($key,1); //remove first character, if only you first key always single char, else you may use your own method to extract key
  if(in_array($new_key,$list)){
    $result[$new_key] = $value;
    unset($list[array_search($new_key, $list)]);//remove used key
  }
}

//push remaining as null
foreach($list as $v){
  $result[$v] = null;
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: If you are going to use `array_search()`, you should not also use `in_array()`.  This answer can be improved logically.

Answer (score 0):

write your custom script

```
$result = [];
foreach($a as $key => $value) $result[trim($key, 'g')] = $value;
foreach($list as $key) if (!isset($result[strval($key)]) $result[strval($key)] = null;
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me.  Also, if you switch the order of the two arrays, you can avoid the if entirely.  Try this: $result = [];
foreach($list as $key) { $result[strval($key)] = null; }
foreach($a as $key => $value) $result[trim($key, 'g')] = $value;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do first is transform the keys in array `$a`. Then use your `$list` of keys to populate null values where none are present in `$a`.

```php
$aKeys = preg_replace('/\D/', '', array_keys($a));
$a = array_combine($aKeys, $a);
$defaultList = array_fill_keys($list, null);
$list = array_merge($defaultList, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop the `$list` array
2. Check if the list value (prepended with `g`) exists in the `$a` array. If so, push it with the desired numeric key into the result array; if not, push it into an alternative array with the desired numeric key and the default value of `null`.
3. When finished iterating, append the data from the alternative array to the result array.

This will properly filter your data, apply the expected default values and sort the output exactly as requested.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/YcRap))

```
foreach ($list as $v) {
    if (isset($a["g$v"])) {
        $result[$v] = $a["g$v"];
    } else {
        $extra[$v] = null;
    }
}
var_export(
    array_replace($result ?? [], $extra ?? [])
);
```

I am using `?? []` to fallback to an empty array in case either of the arrays are never declared (never receive any elements).